# Array of Mat Data type

Tags: opencv

How can I have an array of Mat objects I have used this syntax

```
Mat templat[3]={imread("a.bmp"),imread("b.bmp"),imread("c.bmp")};
```

and by using" for loop".I am trying to access each image one by one but its not working ,What is correct syntax for array of Mat objects 
A part of my code is this

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{

Mat templat[3]={imread("a.bmp"),imread("b.bmp"),imread("c.bmp")};


 imshow("A",templat[0]);

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Even it is not working...and giving error &&size.height>0> is unknown function

Comment: This is correct. It compiles fine and runs correctly for me. You have to be specific by what you mean by it doesn't work. What error messages are you getting? The problem could be elsewhere. You need to provide more context to your code.

Comment: -1 for : "but it's not working." . really, *what* does not work ? don't be so lame ...

Comment: error &&size.height>0  means : one of the images could not be found / loaded. check the path.

Comment: yes, I have checked path of each image ,and if I use this           Mat templat=imread("a.bmp"); imshow("I",templat).It shows image in window I,